# Can't upload test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, change-set

I accidentally (but successfully) uploaded to production via change set an Apex Trigger, without also uploading a Apex Test Class (doh!).

I have the test class created and ready to deploy, but I'm not able to deploy because I get the error "Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 63%, at least 75% test coverage is required".

What is the best course of action.   Can I just change to inactive the trigger that is causing the problems, or delete it or....

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get errors when using Run All Tests?

Comment: Yes, but on Tests from a Managed Package, which I've been told shouldnt affect the overall Code Coverage count.

Comment: Have you only uploaded the original change set or have you uploaded and deployed it?

Comment: uploaded and deployed

Comment: Just to reword again to hope for another response -- the Trigger is already in production - I'm trying to deploy the test class (to fix the code coverage issue - but can't because of code coverage issue).  I've tried uploading the class and trigger together as part of the change set and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVERMIND! Figured out the issue -- we have this in our system -- https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000178fsEAA
And one of the caveats for code coverage is that the system admin profile users have "assignment group" checked.  At some point I must have unchecked them in production.
I checked the box, and rerun tests and now all is good.  Phew...

Comment: Please mark this as the answer to your question so that the system closes it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the change set from production and start again.  You can clone the existing change set in the sandbox it originally came from to serve as a new starting point.  With the test included in the new change set, you should be fine.